# How Do You Right Justify a Block of Left Justified Text?

Tags: positioning, minipage, justification

I have an address block that looks something like the following

```
First_Name Last_Name
Affiliation
Address
Contact Information
```

And I want this block to hug the right side of the page but remain left justified much the same as how the address block in the top right of [this](https://www.latextemplates.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/formal_letter_1-1.jpg) example is formatted. I think something with a minipage might work, but I could not get it to come out right. The minipage width would have to somehow adjust to the max-width of its internals.

Comment: Check out the varwidth package.

Answer (score 7):

In this case it's easiest to set the contents in a `tabular` that has a single, `l`eft-aligned column. These types of columns stretch to fit the maximum width naturally. So, something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\hfill
\begin{tabular}{ l @{}}
  First.Name Last.Name \\
  Affiliation          \\
  Address              \\
  Contact Information
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The `\hfill` pushes the `tabular` as far right as possible - up against the right margin in this case. We also remove the `tabular` column spacing by using `@{}` in the column specification. This puts the widest element in the `tabular` flush with the right margin.

Here's a visual if I include a border around the text block boundary (with `\usepackage{showframe}`):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you still wanna use the `minipage` you could do the same as in [Werner's Answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/594235/150322). Like this:

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}{3.5cm}
    First_Name Last_Name \\
    Affiliation          \\
    Address              \\
    Contact Information
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

But if you are trying to write a letter I highly encourage you to use the `letter` document class like this:

```tex
\documentclass{letter}

\date{%
  \begin{minipage}{3.5cm}
    First_Name Last_Name \\
    Affiliation          \\
    Address              \\
    Contact Information
  \end{minipage}
}
\signature{%
  First_Name Last_Name \\
  Affiliation          \\
  Address              \\
  Contact Information  %%
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{letter}{%
    First_Name Last_Name \\
    Affiliation          \\
    Address              \\
    Contact Information  %%
  }
    \opening{Dear Sir or Madame,}

    Lots of text...

    \closing{Sincerely,}
  \end{letter}
\end{document}
```

The text inside the date command will be indented the way you want by LaTeX but still needs to be wrapped around a box or table. To adjust the `minipage` automatically, you could use a function called `\widthof` from the `calc` package.